# Как запомнить состояние ajax страницы при возврате по кнопке назад

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlet, html5-history-api, history

Мое веб-приложение довольно простое

севлет:

```
String greetings = "Hello from Servlet 1";
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(greetings);
```

скрипт

```
function push1() {
    History.pushState({state:1,rand:Math.random()}, "State 1", "?state=1");
    $.get('servlet_1', {
    }, function(responseText) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
    });
}
```

страница jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.history.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
    <div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="push1()">pushState 1</button>
    <p>
        <a href="help.html">help.html</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Если нажать на кнопку, то приходит `ajax` содержимое на страницу, но после того как перейти на `help.html` и вернуться обратно по кнопке назад в браузере, то jsp страница уже не помнит содержимое котороепришло по аяксу. Как сделать чтобы jsp страница запоминала свое состояние при возврате назад?

Answer (score 1):

Проработать механизм, который при загрузке страницы будет делать нужный ajax-запрос (и т.п.) в зависимости от содержимого адресной строки. Это решит ещё одну задачу - даст возможность поделиться ссылкой, перейдя по которой всё будет выглядеть так как задумано.